# Show $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ does not contain $\sqrt{7}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $\zeta$ be a prmitive $14^{th}$ root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$. We are given that $\sqrt{-7}\in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.

Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ does not contain $\sqrt{7}$.

Comment: Do you know what $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbf{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbf{Q})$ is?

Comment: @BrandonCarter, yes is it possible to prove without using galois theory?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure what motivation there is to not use Galois theory. Since you originally had the `algebraic-number-theory` tag, you could use that 2 is unramified in $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_7)$.

Comment: I can't find it but I swear I have a seen a very similar question in the last month.

Comment: Well, you know $\sqrt{-7} \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$. If $\sqrt{7} \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, then $i \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, which is a primitive $4$th root of unity. Thus $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ contains a primitive $28$th root of unity, which is not true.

Comment: @spin : you know, if $\zeta_7$ is a primitive $7$th root of unity, $\Bbb Q(\zeta_7)$ contains a primitive $14$th root of unity, so I don't think it is immediately obvious that $\Bbb Q(\zeta)$ doesn't contain a primitive $28$th root of unity.

Comment: @mercio: Well, $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{28}) : \mathbb{Q}] = \varphi(28) = 12$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{14}) : \mathbb{Q}] = \varphi(14) = 6$. So if $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{14})$ would contain $\zeta_{28}$, then $12$ would divide $6$.

Comment: @spin Or much simpler If $i \in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ then $4= [\mathbb{Q}(i): \mathbb{Q}] | [\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}]=6$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The degree of the extension is $\phi(14) = 6$. If it contains $\sqrt{7}$ it contains the subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7},\sqrt{-7})$. The degree of this extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $4$, contradicting the tower law since $4\not|6$.

If it's not clear why the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7},\sqrt{-7})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $4$, it is because of the following:

$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7},\sqrt{7}):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7},\sqrt{7}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}):\mathbb{Q}], [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}):\mathbb{Q}]=2$ clearly and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7},\sqrt{7}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})]=1$ or $2$, but $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ is a real subfield so doesn't contain $\sqrt{-7}$.